# React DatePicker: Highlight current month's days

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datepicker

Is there any way to highlight current month's days in [React date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker).

Visually it should look like current month's days are like enabled black colored, and previous-next month's are grey (like disabled, but actually they're still clickable).

```
 <DatePicker
   className="form-control"
   selected={this.props.dateFrom}
   onChange={(momentDate) => {
      this.props.changeDateFrom(momentDate);
   }}
   isClearable={false}
/>
```

Here is preview of example that I would like to create:

[image: Example]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can overwrite the CSS of this class:

- .react-datepicker__day--outside-month

Comment: **.react-datepicker__day--outside-month**  Found it =). Please re-edit your answer so I can mark it as right one.

Answer (score 5):

As Damien suggested you need to over-ride the .react-datepicker__day--outside-month CSS class. The exact CSS would be as below for hiding any dates other than the current month.

```
.react-datepicker__day--outside-month {
  color: transparent !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: to show ouside month dates in disabled color use   `color: #e0e0e0 !important;`